# React Native showing error while making a build in iOS - Build failed The following build commands failed: CompileC

Tags: reactjs, swift, xcode, react-native, npm

Everything was working fine. I just did npm audit fix and this error showed up.

Things I did but didn't work:

I deleted node modules and installed them again. Deleted podfile.lock and tried command pod install. Closed Xcode and restarted it. I tried many alternative StackOverflow solutions but didn't work. Can anyone please help me solving this issue?

```
=== BUILD TARGET toolbar-android OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/jindalsaw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PipeApp-egsumunmosmxkzatcgfjoitkddtm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNGestureHandler.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNGestureHandlerManager.o /Users/jindalsaw/Desktop/zzzz/ReactApp_mobile/PipeApp/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/ios/RNGestureHandlerManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

My podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'

platform :ios, '14.2'


target 'PipeApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

  target 'PipeAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'PipeApp-tvOS' do
  # Pods for RNTodo-tvOS

  target 'PipeApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be cache error from XCode.

Open Xcode Click on File -> Workspace Settings -> click on derive data and delete derive data folder. Clean and build agian.

I have attached screenshot where to click to go to derive data folder.
[image]

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Either try running Xcode with rosetta:
Right click Xcode > get info > Open using Rosetta

Or run from terminal with `npx react-native run` in one and `arch -x86_64 npm run ios` in another